# how Do i Get User's Message Mentioned Text_channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i Want to make A Clear Command But How Do I Get The Mentioned Text_Channel On Message?

I Don't Have Anything To Show Because I Don't Know How To Get Mentioned Channels.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discord.py message object has a [`channel_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel_mentions) attribute that collects all channels that are mentioned in the message. You can use that to access the channels mentioned by the user in your command